# Player stops moving in the air in Godot

Tags: godot

I currently only have a player and a ground object, which both have colliders. The player code looks like this:

```
extends RigidBody2D

var speed := Vector2(500, 0)
var firstFrame = true

func _process(delta):
    position += speed * delta
    print("player    ", position.x)


func _physics_process(delta):
    if (Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_SPACE)  && firstFrame == true):
        apply_force(Vector2(0, -35000))
        firstFrame = false
    if (Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_SPACE) != true):
        firstFrame = true
```

However, the player stops moving while in the air.

This is the only script in the object, and the player and ground are the only two nodes in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

In Godot, Rigid Body nodes should be used for physics simulations/objects, not player controllers. Instead, use a KinematicBody2D(renamed to CharacterBody2D in Godot 4). Here is an example player controller in Godot 4:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

# Constants used by the controller, feel free to change them
const jump := -800
const gravity := 1900
const speed := 500

func _process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta # Making the player fall because of gravity
    
    # Letting the player jump if they're on the ground
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        velocity.y += jump

    # Letting the player move left or right
    velocity.x = Input.get_action_strength("right") - Input.get_action_strength("left") 
    velocity.x *= speed
     
    # Making the player move
    move_and_slide()
```

Godot version 3:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

# Constants used by the controller, feel free to change them
const jump := -800
const gravity := 1900
const speed := 500

var velocity := Vector2.ZERO

func _process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta # Making the player fall because of gravity
    
    # Letting the player jump if they're on the ground
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        velocity.y += jump

    # Letting the player move left or right
    velocity.x = Input.get_action_strength("right") - Input.get_action_strength("left") 
    velocity.x *= speed
     
    # Making the player move
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity,Vector2.UP)
```

To get this to work in either Godot version, you will need to go to `project` and then `project settings`. Then, click on the `Input Actions` tab and add actions named `jump`, `left` and `right`. Using actions is better than using individual keys, since you can easily assign multiple keys to a single action(for example, adding support for both wasd and the arrow keys).

The reason I used `Input.get_action_strength` for left and right movement is because of two reasons:

1. It's easy to use, and replaces if statements
2. It allows the player to only move partially when the player is using the joy stick on a controller.